# Сортировка слиянием и ub

Tags: c++

```
void merge(const int* a1, const int* a2, int* buffer, const int& l1, const int& l2)
{
    int a(0), b(0);

    while(a + b < l1 + l2) 
    {
        if(b >= l2 || a < l1 && a1[a] <= a2[b])
        { 
            buffer[a + b] = a1[a];
            ++a;
        } else { 
            buffer[a + b] = a2[b];
            ++b;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот это логическое выражение b >= l2 || a < l1 && a1[a] < a2[b], разве не будет ub? тк выполняется && при a не вышедшем за длину массива и при b вышедшем - обращение к a2[b], при неком стечении обстоятельств, это не будет ub? Чтение при выходе за границу массива.

Comment: Если предположить (по приведенному коду этого не видно, но наверное так и есть), что l1 + l2 меньше или равно длине массива, то a + b будет гарантированно меньше длины массива, следовательно (т.к. a и b положительны), b не будет выходить за границы массива.
Я могу ошибаться, поэтому чтобы не гадать, приведите код сортировки целиком.

Comment: Непосредственно к вопросу не относится, но если хотите чтобы сортировка была [устойчивой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (обычно от mergesort мы ждем именно этого свойства и поэтому миримся с расходом памяти), то замените `<` в `a1[a] < a2[b]` на `<=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Условие в  `jf` предложении можно записать как

```
if ( ( b >= l2 ) || ( a < l1 && a1[a] < a2[b] ) )
```

Согласно Стандарту С (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator **guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation;** if the second operand is evaluated, there
>   is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated**.

Поэтому сначала вычисляется левый операнд оператора `||`, и только в случае, если результат вычисления равен 0, вычисляется правый операнд оператора.

Так что в этом условие неопределенного поведения нет.

Comment: А приоритет and > or. http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Первым выполнится and по идее или я что то путаю?

Comment: @uskabuska Приоритет означает, что если у вас есть выражение a || b && c, то она интерпретируется как a || ( b && c ), а не как ( a || b ) && c

Comment: @uskabuska  Нет. Даже в выражении a + b * c компилятор может сначала вычислить выражение a, а лишь только затем b * c, Для этих операторов порядок вычисления операндов не специфицирован. А для логических операций ИЛИ и И порядок гарантирует вычисление операндов слева направо.

Comment: Как же я этого не увидел, хаха, замыленный взгляд, надо передохнуть, спасибо.